# CMake-generated Xcode project how to produce universal dSYM

Tags: cmake, dsym, universal-binary

I'm using CMake with Xcode generator to generate Xcode project to build framework for iOS and tvOS (and other platforms too).

I'm setting [`IOS_INSTALL_COMBINED`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/IOS_INSTALL_COMBINED.html) to generate a framework that contains both device and simulator architectures automatically without need of calling `lipo` myself.

The problem is that generated `.framework.dSYM` is not universal, it has only `x86_64` architecture slice. Should I call `lipo` manually anyway to merge it myself? I wanted to avoid it and have CMake/Xcode do all the work.

Comment: Hi Paul / #SOreadytohelp, did you find our how to do this?

Comment: @WizardofKneup Unfortunately no.

Comment: I found the answer for my (similar) issue!I needed to add
    
set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES "$(ARCHS_STANDARD)")

to my CMakeLists.txt file. I was struggling in specifying these two architectures directly as `arm64;x86:64` but like this it works. Unfortunately, it will most likely not help for your case.